# Getaccounts in facebook graph api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is a generic question (though I'm using facebook sdk for android).

If the getaccounts api call gives an empty array does it mean

a) User had previously denied MANAGE_PAGE permission ?
b) User hasn't yet made the request in the app (which then asks for for MANAGE_PAGE permission) ?
c) There are no pages associated with the user account ?

How to differentiate between above 3 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/<ID>/permissions` to differentiate

When user hasnt seen `manage_pages` yet, you should see permissions without `manage_pages` in it

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "user_birthday", 
      "status": "granted"
    }, 
    {
      "permission": "user_likes", 
      "status": "granted"
    }, 
    {
      "permission": "user_events", 
      "status": "granted"
    }, 
    {
      "permission": "user_friends", 
      "status": "granted"
    }, 
    {
      "permission": "email", 
      "status": "granted"
    }, 
    {
      "permission": "ads_management", 
      "status": "granted"
    }, 
    {
      "permission": "public_profile", 
      "status": "granted"
    }, 
  ]
}
```

When user declined `manage_pages` you should see

```
 {
      "permission": "manage_pages", 
      "status": "declined"
    }
```

When all the necessary permissions have been granted and yet the `accounts` is empty, then there are no pages